# How to round decimal number to two decimal places?

Tags: java, freemarker

I have Decimal numbers and I would like to round them to two decimal places.
So for example:

2222.333333 -> 2222.33

51.22 -> 51.22

27.0012 -> 27.00

37.28945 -> 37.29

7891.1 -> 7891.10

Could you tell me how to do this? I have these numbers parsed from xml so all these numbers are strings. I tried to parsing it first to number within `?number` and do somethnig like this:

```
<#return value?number?string('0.##')/>
```

but I'm not sure what should I put into () of `?string` so it could be applied to all these cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
<#return value?number?string('0.00')/>
```

The pattern format is the same as in [DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/DecimalFormat.html).